# How to move layered navigation above toolbar for specific category in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, category, layout, frontend, magento2.2

I'm trying to move **layered navigation** above **description block** for specific category and category page set in full width from **backend** in **Magento 2** but it's not working.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU2yA.png]

Can anyone help or suggest?

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Comment: @Kapil Will you please share your frontend view that How you wants it to look like

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this code May be it will help you in getting what you want

```
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" before="-" />
<move element="category.description" destination="content" after="catalog.leftnav" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`destination="content"`** if you want navigation before toolbar

```
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" before="-" />
```

Comment: Thanks Prince Patel for reply. I have already tried but layered navigation not showing in that category page.